# Is it halal to have oral sex with the spouse?

Tags: halal-haram, sex, husband-wife

Is it permissible for a married couple to engage in oral sex? I heard it was forbidden for men to indulge in oral sex but women can do it as she is liable to please her husband in every possible way. I don't personally believe the above since the source was not a reliable one. What's the Islamic verdict on this issue?

Answer (score 6):

### Lack of consensus

Surveying fatawa on the topic (see below), we see there is no consensus on the matter of oral sex.  This lack of consensus is affirmed by the following fatwa:

> As for what you mentioned, i.e. sucking, licking or oral sex, there is no clear evidence from the Qur’an or Hadith concerning them. **The scholars of Islam differed on this matter. Some believe that it is forbidden, others believe that it is lawful.** -- [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=81994%3Cbr%3E)

IslamWeb didn't offer a definite ruling on the matter, but go on to write:

> This kind of pleasure is far from the natural dispositions that Allah has created us with.

Likewise, a lack of consensus is also raised in [al-Fatawa al-Hindiyya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatawa-e-Alamgiri) (sourced from [Darul Iftaa](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/5680)):

> “If a man inserts his penis in his wife’s mouth, it is said that it is disliked (makruh), and others said that it is not disliked.” (al-Fatawa al-Hindiyya, 5/372)

### The arguments presented

The main arguments I encountered are:

1. There will be najis (impurities) entering the mouth (which is used to recite the Qur'an), which should be avoided; ingesting these is haram.  (Possibilities here are using e.g. a condom, simply being careful.)
2. Some scholars' opinions are that it is inherently immoral or disgusting (describing it like behaving like animals or non-Muslims); it is befitting of Muslims to have a natural sense of morality, and shame and modesty (hayaa), e.g.

   > ...people of high morality normally keep away from that... -- [AskImam.com](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/17570)
3. It is important to maintain sexual relations between spouses.  If it's viewed as halal, a Muslim wife could be requested to perform this, whereas if it's viewed as haram, she should refuse.

---

### What to do?

- Abstaining from oral sex is a sin-free possibility, albeit it's not so easy for the obedient wife whose husband requests it.
- One bears the responsibility of one's own decisions:

  > And no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another. ... -- [Qur'an 35:18](https://quran.com/35:18)
- In [The Response](http://www.fixyourdeen.com/htm/final/) (described as "the result of a lengthy collaboration between scholars of Egypt’s prestigious Al-Azhar University and Islamic Hotline or El-Hatef El-Islami organization"):

  > ...there is nothing wrong in approaching more than one scholar regarding a single matter, and then to **make one's own decision as to which opinion to follow**. -- Dr. Yassir ‘Abd al-‘Azim, [The Response](http://www.fixyourdeen.com/htm/final/qacategorysub20.asp)

  In this case, there's respectable scholarly arguments either way.

---

### Who says it's halal

> Basically married couples are allowed to enjoy each other’s body as they wish except what is forbidden, i.e. anal sex, or having sex during menses or confinement period. -- [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=87423%3Cbr%3E)
>
> Yes, it is permissible for both the man and the woman to do what has been mentioned in the question, since every form of sexual enjoyment is permissible between husband and wife except for (1) anal intercourse and (2) deriving pleasure from what is between the navel and knee of women in menstruation or post-natal bleeding. -- Amjad Rasheed, Qibla.com, sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/33513)
>
> In conclusion, in our School oral sex is permissible. -- Shafiifiqh.com Fatwa Dept., sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/shafii/shafiifiqh/30094)
>
> It is permissible provided no liquid out swallowed. -- Ayatullah Sistani, sourced from [alulbayt.com](http://www.alulbayt.com/rulings/11.htm)

### Who say it's halal, yet makrooh (disliked)

> Oral sex is Makrooh. If a person does it to arouse the sensations during foreplay and the impurities do not enter the mouth then it is not a sin. It is permissible to kiss or lick the genital area before intercourse in order to arouse and stimulate the sensations.  -- Mufti Muhammad Ashraf, sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/mahmoodiyah/54043)
>
> Our view on the matter is that oral sex is makruh tahrimi -- Checked and approved by Mufti Ebrahim Desai, [AskImam.org](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/30895) (also [here](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/23726), [here](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/17678), [here](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/28333), and [here](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/15982); also note the three contradictory fatawa by this Mufti below)
>
> This is amongst the reasons why  the  Fuqaha have ruled that oral sex is Makruh Tahrimi (reprehensible). -- Checked and concurred by Moulana Ismail Desai, [AskImam.org](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/21483) (also [here](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/21483))
>
> There is no doubt that [the request of] this practise from the husband of the questioner is a disgusting practise and obviously disliked. -- Shaykh 'Abdullaah ibn Munay', [Fatwa-Online.com](http://www.fatwa-online.com/regarding-oral-sex/)

### Who says it's haram

> if oral sex entails swallowing or likely swallowing of filthy substances–such as pre-sexual discharge–then it is prohibitively disliked and sinful -- Faraz Rabbani, Qibla.com, sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/42916)
>
> Every form of oral sex is prohibited. There is no difference in the ruling between the front and hind parts. Sex is a human need and natural. However Shariah has emphasized on shame and modesty. -- Mufti Ebrahim Desai, [AskImam.org](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/15792) (also [here](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/28092) and [here](http://askimam.org/public/question_detail/11873.html))
>
> If the “oral sex” includes the penis being inserted in the wife’s mouth to the extent that she swallows the filth, whether this filth is semen (Mani) or pre-ejaculatory fluid (Madhi), or the man takes the filth of the woman in his mouth, then this will not be permissible. (Fatawa Rahimiyah p.270 v.6 & Fatawa Hindiyya p.372 v.5) -- Mohammed Tosir Miah, [Darul Iftaa](http://daruliftabirmingham.co.uk/oral-sex/)
>
> If “oral sex” means to insert the penis in the wife’s mouth to the extent that she takes in the filth, whether this filth is semen (Mani) or pre-ejaculatory fluid (Madhi), or the man takes the filth of the woman in his mouth, then this is not permissible. Taking the filth with all its forms in the mouth is unlawful. The fluids which come out are impure, thus make it impermissible to take it orally. -- Mufti Muhammad ibn Adam, [Darul Iftaa](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/5680) (also [here](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/5654) and [here](http://www.daruliftaa.com/node/5594))
>
> Oral sex is a dispicable act and is impermissible. -- Mufti Shafiq Jakhura and Mufti Zubair Bayat, sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/darulihsan/76604) (also [here](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/darulihsan/76717))
>
> This habit was never thought of during that Golden era of the Sahabah radiyallahu anhum (In fact , not even here a few decades ago) so you won’t find hadeeth regarding it. You will have to use your brains for such a clear cut mas’ala. The muftees say it’s not allowed. Mufti Abdur Raheem Lajpoori Rahmatullahi alayhi has mentioned this in his fataawa. -- Mufti Abdur Raheem Lajpoori, Tafseer Raheemi, sourced from [IslamQA.org](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/tafseer-raheemi/51568)
>
> No it is not permissible because precum will most probably enter the mouth and precum is najis (impure). Also the mouth is used for recitation of quraan, etc not for such degrading acts. Licking will assume the same answer. As for kissing this will also be undesirable. -- [Council of Ulama Eastern Cape](http://www.councilofulama.co.za/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=522:oral-sex&catid=55:adult-content&Itemid=56)
>
> We have a general principle, and that is the Messenger (sal-Allaahu ‘alayhi wa sallam) forbade [us from] resembling the animals in other than what we are talking about (oral sex) -- Shaykh Muhammad Naasiruddeen al-Albaanee, [Fatwa-Online.com](http://www.fatwa-online.com/regarding-oral-sex/)
>
> The mouth is an organ that is used to take the name of Allah Ta'ala and recite the Quraan. Hence one should refrain from using the mouth for despicable acts. Furthermore this action has a resemblance with the ways of the kuffaar and the way of the animals.  -- Mufti Zakaria Makada, [MuftiOnline.co.za](http://muftionline.co.za/node/1552)

(Technically, this last Mufti didn't actually say "haram", etc.)

Comment: *"Furthermore this action has a resemblance with the ways of the kuffaar and the way of the animals. -- Mufti Zakaria Makada, MuftiOnline.co.za"* If he plays this card than late Ahmed Deedat used to mention about sex on his debates as "act of lower animal function". So sex itself is an animal function. Perhaps these "scholars" quit doing it.

Comment: Good comprehensive overview, interesting to note those against are almost all Deobandi. One correction - *makruh tehreemi* is an act considered so disliked that it is forbidden, and afaik is applied to those things that scholars have decided is impermissible based on analogy (as opposed to impermissible based on direct textual evidence, i.e. *haraam*). Therefore the fatwah from Ebrahim Desai would be consistent with his other statements: he argues there's no specific evidence from the Qur'an or the Sunnah to say it's haraam, but based on analogy he concludes it's disliked and forbidden.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it is permissible for Muslims to perform acts of oral sex with their spouses. Licking or sucking the spouse's sexual organs are permissible, as long as it gives a person sexual satisfaction which will keep him/her away from Haram acts or starring at non-Mahram men/women. But if it leads to releasing of semen, then it is Makruh (disliked), but there is no clear evidence that forbids it.

> “If a man inserts his penis in his wife’s mouth, it is said that it is
>   disliked (makruh), and others said that it is not disliked.”
>   (al-Fatawa al-Hindiyya, 5/372)

Answer (score 4):

As in previous answers it is said, there is no specific ruling on restriction on this. But fluids are NAJIS. Best fatwa on this is got states "Everything and every part of our body has a specific purpose and use. We should not use that part other than that. And purpose of mouth is not to do such things. So we should try not to do it."

For more detailed answers See [this](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=81994%3Cbr%3E) and [this](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=87423%3Cbr%3E) fatwa on islamweb.

Comment: Well i know that Sheikh al Quradawi was asked this in his program on Iqra' and answered that it is permissible. This fatwa made a great éclat, but i didn't watch the program so i don't know the details of his answer!

Comment: He is right, as i said in my answer that there are no specific rulings on this in islam. SO it will be considered permissible as all things we do not cosidering them part of islam or part of deen are permissible as long as we don't find any rulings against them. And all matters we do considering them part of islam or deen and thinking that we will get reward for them are considered forbidden as long as we find a ruling on the matter to do so. This is a basic rule we should all know.

Comment: From a theological POV the explanation about the use of the mouth might be acceptable. But i guess one could find counter-examples for this kind of explanation which may lead to a contradiction of theologians!

Comment: Yes thats why link are given which has SHARAI explanation of this matter. And theological answers are not to rely upon they are just to build case, nothing else.

Comment: Brother Zia could you quote a specific text which says the male and female sexual fluids are najis?

Answer (score 2):

I have heard this is a difference of opinion among the scholars.

But the opinion I follow is that it is permissible for both the husband and the wife. I adopted this because there is no specific text forbidding it (like there is for anal sex for example or sex when the woman is in her menses). If Allah (swt) wanted it to be forbidden, He would specified it as in the above cases, so why do we seek to make unlawful what He (swt) has not.

I also do not see why it would be permissible only for the husband (there is no text for this position either). You said "she is liable to please her husband in every possible way", does not the wife also have this right upon her husband?

Allah Knows best and may He guide us all, Ameen!

Answer (score 2):

There is no Islamic verdict that makes it impermissible, and there are different scholar opinions about it. However, what one should keep in mind is that such practice should generate pleasure for both the one initiating it and the one receiving it. Religion should not be used as a pressuring card to force the husband/wife to please the other as a successful intimacy requires two people's satisfaction.

Answer (score -2):

You will find that fatwas and threads by laymen go round in circles discussing if it is haraam or not. I believe that oral sex was known at that time as there is a Hadith in Bukhari where Abu Bakr (RA) says to an unbeliever to "suck the clitoris of al-Lat".http://www.letmeturnthetables.com/2013/05/suck-clitoris-lat-befitting-response-abu-bakr.html

A husband receiving oral wearing a condom should clear najis issues but not sure if the husband can cover the female part (cling film?) to avoid direct contact. However, mouth to private part direct would be much more enjoyable for both! Fruit flavoured condoms are available to help the wife have a nice taste when sucking.

It is ironic though that non Muslims are so free with oral and we are not yet we WASH every time we visit the toilet including passing water so in that sense our parts are clean (maybe soap could be used before the act).

Personally I think if a Muslim realises that there is no clear cut evidence against the act (there is scholarly difference) then he will become frustrated not to receive oral and same for wife as surely it is pleasurable.