# Homosexuality and Heterosexuality

Tags: halal-haram, sexuality, contradiction

I am a homosexual individual and I am having a question that concerns me a lot!! As homosexuality is halal as a finding to intensive research I mad, why anal sex is haram for heterosexuals???

Comment: There's no disagreement about homosexual acts being haram. There's however a dispute about anal sex. The majority view considers it haram, some even say that the opinion allowing it is based on a misunderstanding from a tab'iy.

Answer (score 1):

Homosexuality is prohibited in Islam.

Homosexuality is a test for some people just as heterosexuality is a test for most people.

Refer to:

[Is it permissible to have non-penetrative gay sex (e.g. oral sex) or anal sex using a condom?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/37221/is-it-permissible-to-have-non-penetrative-gay-sex-e-g-oral-sex-or-anal-sex-us)

Comment: You can find a spouse as a heterosexual, but you have no such chance as a homosexual.

Comment: Yes, but if someone is deemed very homosexual to the point they don’t get aroused by women or don’t believe they’ll live a good life with a woman instead of a man, they should live their life single.

Comment: That's what I am saying. Their test is quite different, and much harder.

Comment: @SpiderRico Many people aren't able to have a spouse for various reasons and die without marrying.

Comment: @TheZ They might try, and fail. Homosexuals don't even have a chance try.